# How can I use http request on android in java

Tags: android, http, post, get, httprequest

There was a problem in my project. Since I am new to http request, I do not know how to use it, the code I use for this issue is attached.

```
 public  String httpPost(String url, String method, List<NameValuePair> params, int time) {

    //url: post yapilacak adres
    //method: post mu get mi
    //params:post edilecek veriler degiskenler
    //time: sunucudan cevap gelmezse kaç sn sonra uygulama donmadan postun iptal edilecegi
    try {
        if (method == "POST") {
            BasicHttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
            setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, time);
            setSoTimeout(httpParameters, time);
            HttpResponse httpResponse;
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "UTF-8"));
                httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            veri =  httpEntity.getContent();

        } else if (method == "GET") {
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            veri =  httpEntity.getContent();
        }

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        @SuppressLint({"NewApi", "LocalSuppress"})
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(veri, StandardCharsets.UTF_8), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        veri.close();
        veri_string = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Hata " + e.toString());
    }
    return veri_string; // Aldığımız cevabın string halini geri dönüyoruz
}
```

}

The error I get when I use this is also attached.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4xCy.jpg)

How can I solve this problem or how can I get post with http request? I would appreciate if there is someone to help. thanks in advance

Comment: These days there are about 100 libraries to help you do this in a much more efficient and less error prone manner. So unless you are writing such a library yourself I'd suggest simply using them. Volley being one of them https://developer.android.com/training/volley

Comment: You can use retrofit too